# How to check if data exist in Firebase with Angularfire2 and then fetch it using 'if/else' statement

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I work on a project using Angular2 with Angulafire2 / Firebase. I can fetch lists and objects without problems but when I want to render individual item page with details, I can't 'switch' to the second node (to fetch item details) if requested ID is not in the first one. I have tried several 'if/else' approaches (here is one where I try to confirm that ID has some value in key 'title') but all without luck -- app always recognize just one node. Please, can someone advise me how to correct this?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.less']
})

export class itemComponent implements OnInit {
item: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
constructor( private af:AngularFire, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

ngOnInit() {
this.route.params
  .map( params => {
    return params["id"]
  })
  .subscribe(id => {
    const itemID = this.af.database.object(`items/${id}`, { preserveSnapshot: true })
    itemID.subscribe(snapshot => {
        if( snapshot.val().key !== null ) {
        this.item = this.af.database.object(`items/${id}`);
        } else {
        this.item = this.af.database.object(`items01/${id}`);
        }
      });
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: same issue, did you have any solution for it?